# Menus don't work in Notepad on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, notepad

I'm trying to use normal Windows Notepad on Windows 8.

When I click an item on the menu bar to bring down the menu, nothing happens.

All other applications work fine, only Notepad is affected.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Try to restart it then click `ALT+F`, does it help ?

Comment: @matan129: A screenshot of Notepad with no menus displayed - how would that help? :)

Comment: Yes, that what I meant. Are the menus just inactive or completely disappear?

Comment: The menus are there. When you hover over a menu item it turns blue and then when you click it turns a different shade of blue so it's definitely registering the click, it's just that no menu pops down. Similarly with alt-f, the underlines appear and the file menu turns blue but no menu pops down. Things like control-s work OK though. I should add that I've been using (and programming) Windows for about 20 years so it's unlikely to be a user error :-)